# How to show image base64 with upload manually in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I uploading file with Upload Manually in Ant Design but it not able to show preview image as base64. I want to show preview image base64 as picture card when I picked image from browser. How I can fix it?

My code upload:

```
const FormPost = () => {
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
    const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

    const onFinish = (values) => {
        console.log('Success:', values);
    };
    const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
        console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
    };

    const normFile = (e) => {
        console.log('Upload event:', e);
        if (Array.isArray(e)) {
            return e;
        }
        return e?.fileList;
    };

    const uploadProps = {
        onRemove: (file) => {
            const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
            const newFileList = fileList.slice();
            newFileList.splice(index, 1);
            setFileList(newFileList);
        },
        beforeUpload: (file) => {
            setFileList([...fileList, file]);
            return false;
        },
        listType: 'picture-card',
        fileList,
    };

    return (
        <Form layout="vertical" name="new-post" onFinish={onFinish} onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed} autoComplete="off">

            <Form.Item label="Upload" valuePropName="fileList" getValueFromEvent={normFile}>
                <Upload {...uploadProps}>
                    <div>New photo</div>
                </Upload>
            </Form.Item>

        </Form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question in my mind some days ago. The key is to use `["thumbUrl"]` attribute of the file user selected. This is how I solved it:

If it is how you have `Upload` component defined:

```
<Upload                               
      action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
      listType="picture-card"
      fileList={params.fileList}
      onChange={params.onChange}
      onPreview={params.onPreview}
      >
             {params.fileList.length === 0 && '+ Upload'}
</Upload>
```

It should be the `Image` component you are trying to show the user:

```
<Image
     width={'80%'}
     height={'60%'}
     src={params.fileList[0]["thumbUrl"]}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i trying with Upload Manually and I want to show preview image as base64 before upload. I don't know how to handle it

Comment: @Táo Have you resolved the issue ?

Comment: @emre-ozgun yep, i has resolved this issue. This is my way:    

 `beforeUpload: async (file) => {
        file.url = await getBase64(file); 
        setFileList([...fileList, file]);
  }`.
Preview as image base64 will show when existing `url` key in object